Send Files from Android to SQL Database in KOTLIN
I am new to Kotlin and my android app is built in Kotlin, that I have learnt as I went along with a tutorial. I have a QR Scanner app that allows me to scan a set of texts and show it on the app.
Now, I would like to ask if how I can send that data to my SQL Server.
I made an SQL server sample and I would like that once scanned, I can make a button when tapped that will send that QR code to the sql server I made.
The thing is I can't seem to find any solution written in Kotlin.
Thank you in advance.
I tried searching online, but most are written in Java and some even require dependencies that are written in Java, that I don't know how to translate to Kotlin.
